# Adding random number of buttons dynamically and setting onClickListener in Android

Tags: android

I am adding buttons dynamically and the number of dynamically added buttons change when I press some other button.

How to set on click listener for each dynamically added button. (number of buttons can change)

This is my code:

```
final LinearLayout llNearbyPlaceslist = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.nearby_places_list);
try{
    llNearbyPlaceslist.removeAllViews();
    for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
        //Log.e("Places",p.name);
        // Getting and placing list of places in Scroll View

                Button btn = new Button(UserClass.this);
                btn.setText(p.name);
                NBPbuttonsList.add(btn);
                llNearbyPlaceslist.addView(btn);   


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set each listener in place:

After:

```
Button btn = new Button(UserClass.this);
```

Add this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener....
```